# Kafka offset is stuck in consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I'm running this kafka command:

```
/opt/kafka_2.11/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server xxxxx:9092 \
  --describe --group flink-cg
```

Result is like this:

```
TOPIC           PARTITION   CURRENT-OFFSET   LOG-END-OFFSET     LAG    
my_topic           0          481239571       484028280       2788709
```

The offset keep stuck although my flink is running and have no error in the log file.

How to check if the number of my offset is correct? I'm afraid my current-offset is having wrong number so the value is stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The sole fact that Flink Job is running doesn't necesarily mean that the offset should change. This depends on the configuration of Your job, but by default the offset is only commited on checkpoint, so the first thing to check is if Your job is properly checkpointing (maybe You have configured long time between checkpoints).

If it is or if You have enabled `enable.auto.commit` then You should check if there is possibly a backpressure for some operators that may be causing problems with reading of records.

It would be easier to tell if You could provide more info about configuration and the job itself.